# Code changes automatically when inputting data with php, mysqli, procedural

Tags: php, html, css

my table name "pelanggan"

```
my structure table -> id_pelanggan -> primary key -> auto increment
                      username
                      email
                      alamat
                      telp
                      password
```

register page

```
<?php require_once "core/init.php";

$error='';

if( isset($_POST['submit']) ){
  $nama   = $_POST['username'];
  $email  = $_POST['email'];
  $alamat = $_POST['alamat'];
  $telp   = $_POST['telp'];
  $pass   = $_POST['password'];


if(!empty(trim($nama)) && !empty(trim($email)) && !empty(trim($alamat)) && !empty(trim($telp)) && !empty(trim($pass)) ){



  if(register_cek_nama($nama) ){
    //memasukan database
          if(register_user($nama, $email, $alamat, $telp, $pass)) {
            $error= 'berhasil daftar register';
          }else{
            $error= 'gagal register';}
      }else{
      $error= ' nama sudah ada, tidak bisa daftar ';}
  }else{
      $error= 'form tidak boleh kosong';
  }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title></title>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified css -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="view/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- optional theme-->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="view/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <!--my custom css-->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="view/css/style.css">
  <!--font-awesome-->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="view/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<!---------------------------------->

<style>

body{

  font-family: arial monospace;
  background-color :#eee;
}

.container{

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;}

.page{

padding:5px;
margin-top: 40px;
margin-bottom: 40px;
height: 510px;
width: 400px;
background: #fff;
}

.content{
  height: 100%;
  padding: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.logo-register h2{
  font-family:Chaparral Pro Light;
font-weight: bold;
}

.logo-register h5{
  font-family: calibri;
  color:#808080;
  border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
  padding-bottom: 5px;

}

.form-group .form-control{
  border-radius: 0;
  border:1px solid #eee;
  padding: 5px;
}

.bawah-submit h5{  font-family: calibri;
                                color:#808080;}

.punya-akun h5{font-family: calibri;
                    color:#808080;}

  #error{color: rgb(212, 19, 65);
                    }









</style>


</head>

<body>


              <div class="container">

                          <div class="page">
                                <div class="content">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="logo-register">
                                                <h2><a href="index.php">Wherco</a></h2>
                                              <h5>Buat akun untuk melakukan order</h5>
                                        </div>


                                              <?php
                                                  if(isset($_SESSION['msg'])) { ?>
                                                <div id="error">
                                                    <?php echo $_SESSION['msg'];
                                                    unset($_SESSION['msg']); ?>
                                                </div> <br>
                                              <?php }  ?>

                                        <?php if($error != ' '){ ?>
                                            <div id="error">
                                                <?php echo $error; ?>
                                            </div>
                                          <?php } ?>


                                  <form class="form-horizontal" action="register.php" method="post">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                             <input type="text" class="form-control" style="text-transform:lowercase;"  name="username" placeholder="Nama lengkap" Required autofocus>
                                          </div>

                                          <div class="form-group">
                                               <input type="email" class="form-control"  name="email" placeholder="Alamat email" Required>
                                          </div>

                                          <div class="form-group">
                                              <textarea class="form-control" rows="3"  name="alamat" placeholder="Alamat tinggal" Required autofocus ></textarea>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                 <input type="number" class="form-control"  name="telp" placeholder="Nomer yang bisa di hubungi" Required>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                 <input type="password" style="text-transform:lowercase;"  class="form-control" name="password"   id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Kata sandi untuk akun order" Required>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                              <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block" value="Daftar">
                                            </div>


                                            <div class="bawah-submit">
                                                    <h5> Dengan mendaftar anda menyetujui Ketentuan<br>
                                                    dan Kebijakan Privasi kami </h5>
                                          </div>

                                          <div class="punya-akun">
                                            <h5> Punya akun? <a href="login.php">Masuk</a> </h5>
                                          </div>
                                </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                    </div
```

function register user

```
<?php

function register_user($nama, $email, $alamat, $telp, $pass){
global $connect;


//mencegah sql injection
$nama   = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $nama);
$email  = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $email);
$alamat = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $alamat);
$telp   = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $telp);
$pass   = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $pass);




$pass = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);


  $query = "INSERT INTO pelanggan (username, email, alamat, telp, password) VALUES ('$nama', '$email', '$alamat', '$telp', '$pass')";

  if( mysqli_query($connect, $query) ){

        return true;
      }else{
        return false;
  }
}
?>
```

My question is how to make the id number of my table change automatically. Example: from id "02" to "customer02" or "p02" when I input data.

I want users not to know what code they get, when creating an account.
I don't know how to declare the query.
thanks

Comment: What table? I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: I've edited this question, please check. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just append it to the beginning of your variable.

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$id = "Customer".$id;
```

Comment: but I did my id with auto increment. I've edited this question, please check. thanks

Comment: I you want an auto increment it should be done within your table having the ID as auto increment on the database side..